# Driver alternative with python in nodes?

Tags: python, compositing-nodes, drivers

I have created a node group in a script. So that the Blur Node can be used on X and Y, I have inserted Driver. The problem is that the node cannot be duplicated, because the drivers in the duplicated nodes do not work anymore. Is there an alternative to this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue but I did try replicate your setup and introduced an error into the driver within the Blur Node. I was still able to duplicate it. Can you attach your blend file sample where the problem is reproducible?

Comment: Blend file attached.

Comment: I opened your file and did a `SHIFT+D` on the group node and it duplicates it without errors. Or is there another method we should use to duplicate it?

Comment: Please take a look at the GIF animation. Yes, the drivers appear without error, but they do not take into account the node input of the copied node, but of the original node.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you copy a group of nodes, ".001" is added to the name of the copy.
[image]

but the name of the first group of nodes is written in the copied nodes in the driver ("Group")

[image]

you need to change the name "Group" to "Group.001" in the driver and everything will work

[image]

Comment: That's the situation, yes. The Question is: Is there an alternative? I would like to deliver Add-ons where the user is not supposed to change Driver Settings.

Comment: @Andi It's really strange. Blur should have inputs for x and y. I think this should be fixed in the future.